# Pass Value Between Pipelines

Tags: drone.io

I have a drone file containing multiple pipelines that run in a sequence via dependancies.

In the first pipeline a value is generated that I would like to store as a variable and use in one of the other pipelines.

How would I go about doing this? I’ve seen that variables can be passed between steps via a file but this isn’t possible with pipelines from what i’ve seen and tried.

Thanks